# Send Info after browserHistory.goBack

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building an App with reactjs and in some point I have a SearchForm, then I click on one of the items and in that view I have a back button.

What I want is to populate the search form with the previous data. I already achieved it with localStorage from javascript. And saving the state on componentWillUnmount, the problem is this data is always loaded even if I don't arrive from the go back.

Is there a way to add a kind of state to the goBack to tell it?

Answer (score 0):

So, the best way here is to not use localStorage, and instead use history state.

When the user updates the form, you can do this (optionally debounce it for better performance):

```
history.replaceState(this.props.location.pathname, {
  formData: JSON.stringify(formData),
});
```

Then when the component loads, you can access that state like this:

```
const {location} = this.props;
const routeState = location.state && location.state.formData;
if (routeState) {
  this.setState({
    data: JSON.parse(routeState),
  });
}
```

If they refresh the page, or go to another page and go back, or go back and then go forward, they'll have that state. If they open it in a new tab, they won't have the state. This is usually the flow you want.

Comment: that history is from ReactJS?

Comment: I tried that way (add to change that location to history) but the behaviour is the same. If hit the back button is ok, but if I go to the homepage, than go back to search still have the same form data that I saved previous